# function sendMailonChange: with a gmail adress in the google form the script does not work

Tags: google-apps-script

let's try it with my first post:

1. a form, embed on a website: it works well
2. a script read out the dates (adress+mail+etc) and send it formatted to a email-adress.
3. read out name and email should be the sender of the mail. This works well, but not with a gmail adress! Debugger said: Invalid argument: ****@gmail.com
4. with all other sender it works well

Code:

```js
GmailApp.sendEmail(senderMail, 'Vereinsmitgliedschaft', '', {
  from: '****@gmail.com',
  name: anmVorname + ' ' + anmName,
  htmlBody: '<b>' + anmValue + '</b> <br><br>' + anmVorname + ' ' + anmName + ' <br>' + anmStrasse + '<br>' + anmOrt + '<br>' + anmMail + '<br>' + anmStatus + '<br><br>' + anmAnmerkung,
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Gabriel,

Can you make sure you are logged into the ****@gmail.com account when you are executing the script?  I think you must be logged in to the account you are trying to send from.

Also, the from value must be one of your aliases. This is explained in Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app).

It describes the Advanced Parameter from:

from    String

the address that the email should be sent from, **which must be one of the values returned by getAliases().**

**getAliases():**

Gets a list of the emails that are set up as aliases for this account in Gmail. You can send a message from any of these aliases by using the "from" optional argument.

So run this code in your apps script, before your code:

```
 // Log the aliases for this Gmail account and send an email as the first one.
 var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
 Logger.log(aliases);
```

Now look at the log data and/or switch on the debugger in Apps Script, to check the values in the  aliases variable.

If ****@gmail.com is not one of values in the aliases var, then that could be the cause of your error... let me know how it works out.